# Can a percentile simultaneously refer to the % below or equal to a score and the % above and equal to a score?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentage

I realise there are several definitions of a percentile. Recently I was given the following definition

Definition 1- A percentile is the percentage of scores lower than or equal to it

I was then asked whether one could infer that the percentile could refer to the percentage of scores above and equal to the percentile.

e.g. 75th percentile means that 25% of observations were greater than or equal to the rank

It seems to me that if you use the definition I was given, you would be doubling up and it would be more accurate to say that 24% of observations where above the 75th percentile. Is this right?

Comment: The definition is strictly utterly wrong, so distrust the source. **The percentile is not a percentage in the sense given**. Otherwise all medians would equal 50%. The percentile is a score (in your terminology; I don't think that is a good general word but leave that on one side) defined and labelled by the percent of scores below it. Equally the definition implies that the complementary percent is above it. That still leaves small print about handling ties, whether to interpolate, and more generally giving precise rules for finite samples, which you evidently are aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), so it has a set of possible outcomes, where all the possible $x$'s are elements of this set. This means that if

$$ \Pr(X \leq x) = p $$

then

$$ \Pr(X > x) = 1-p $$

so knowing percentage below, you also know the percentage above. Saying it differently, if you take subset of all the possible $x$'s such that $X \leq x$, than subset $X > x$ is a complement of the previous subset. This is directly related to [Kolmogorov's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms), since second axiom states that probability of all the possible outcomes is one (i.e. all the individual probabilities sum up to $1$), so if we subtract from the total probability probabilities of some outcomes, then we will be left with sum of probabilities for all the other outcomes.

Comment: This makes sense. But how do you derive the second from the first?

Answer (score 2):

By convention, the cumulative distribution function is defined by
$$F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x)$$
rather than
$$F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(X< x)$$
Therefore, it is also conventional to define an $\alpha$-quantile $q_\alpha$ by
$$F_X(q_\alpha)=\mathbb{P}(X\le q_\alpha)=\alpha$$
and to define its empirical version as
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}(X_i\le \hat{q}_\alpha)\le\alpha$$
i.e., $$\hat{q}_\alpha=X_{(\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor)}$$
the $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor$-th order statistic for the sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

In terms of your question, an $\alpha$-quantile $q_\alpha$ also satisfies
$$1-F_X(q_\alpha)=\mathbb{P}(X> q_\alpha)=1-\alpha$$
which means that the proportion of realisations of $X\sim F_X$ *strictly* larger than $q_\alpha$ is $1-\alpha$. In your terms, this means the percentage of scores strictly *above* to the $n$-th percentile is $(100-n)\%$. Not *above or equal*. In absolutely continuous settings, it does not make a difference to use *above* or *above or equal*, because $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$ but in discrete cases it obviously may. So, if $q_{.75}$ is the $75\%$ percentile, we cannnot deduce which percentage of the sample is above or equal to $q_{.75}$. It is at least $25\%$.

> To state that *$24\%$ of the sample is strictly above the $75\%$ percentile* is
>   thus incorrect since the right percentage is $25\%$.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this relate to my question? I want to know whether there is a contradiction in the definitions.

Comment: This is certainly one convention, as far as I know the more common one,  but some people use the opposite $\mathbb{P}(X < x)$. That seems common in studies of reliability data. The flavour of your answer is only changed trivially.

Comment: @NickCox: thank you. In the older French books about probability, the cdf was actually defined with a strict inequality.

Comment: The great thing about conventions is that there are so many to choose from. (Well, 2 in this case.)